# Android: Drawing 2D Rectangle over a Background Image

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to draw a 2D Rectangle on my Android project. It's working great, but the only problem is that I'm using a Background image for my project. The 2D Rectangle won't allow the Background image to show. For example, if I draw the rectangle before showing the Background image, the Background will hide the rectangle. It'll do the same if I show the Background first and then draw the rectangle, only this time the rectangle will hide the Background image completely.

```
public class DrawView extends View
{
Paint paint = new Paint();
public DrawView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(33,  60, 77, 77, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(33,  33, 77, 60, paint);
    }
}
```

On the main form:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DrawView drawview = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(drawview);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `super.onDraw()` into your `onDraw()` override, to make view's `onDraw()` execute before you start draw custom elements on it:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
   canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
   paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
   canvas.drawRect(33,  60, 77, 77, paint);
   paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   canvas.drawRect(33,  33, 77, 60, paint);
}
```

Comment: you want this rectangle to be kind 'translucent', to make background be showed through it?

Comment: Yes. When I draw one of them (Rectangle or the Background Image) it hides the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. All that's left is changing the rectangle's location.
Add the following:

```
addContentView(drawview, new LayoutParams(Width, Height));
```

And remove the setContentView() command.